# Prolog - return value from base case

Tags: prolog, logic

Ok, here's the deal:

- I've got two piles of shirts
- I want to take a random shirt from each pile and put them in a new pile
- Then get the new pile out

And here is the code:

```
mix([],[],_).
mix(P1,P2, Pile):-
    takeshirt(P1,1,Taken1,Rem1), takeshirt(P2,1,Taken2,Rem2), #Take one
    append(Pile,Taken1,New),     append(New,Taken2,NewPile),  #Put both of them
    mix(Remain1,Remain2,NewPile).
```

This is what the result look like:

```
1 ?- mix([a,b],[c,d],NewPile).
NewPile = [] .
```

I want it to look like:

```
1 ?- mix([a,b],[c,d],NewPile).
NewPile = [b, d, a, c] .
```

Or whatever the result is. I checked via the graphical debugger and found out that when the final call to **mix** happens, the bindings are:

```
P1 = Taken1 = [b]
P2 = Taken2 = [c]
Pile           = [a, d]
Rem1 = Rem2 = []
New         = [a, d, b]
NewPile     = [a, d, b, c] #<--- Interresting
```

So the wanted value is in NewPile when the final call to:

```
mix([],[],_).
```

happens. After this is it collapses like a house of cards.

**So the question is:**

```
mix([],[],_).
```

I'd like to return the _ value from the base case, this rule **mix** is actually used from a higher instance where I send in two piles and get the new pile out.

**Update:**
To clarify some comments about the **takeshirt** rule, here it is:

```
takeshirt(_,0,[],_).
takeshirt(List,Number,[Element|Taken],Remain) :- N > 0,
    length(List,Len),
    Index is random(Len) + 1,
    removeshirt_at(Element,List,Index,Remain),
    Number1 is Number - 1,
    takeshirt(Remain,Number1,Taken,Remain).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following modifications to your code:

```
mix([], [], []) :- !.
mix(P1, P2, Pile) :-
    takeshirt(P1, 1, Taken1, Rem1), 
    takeshirt(P2, 1, Taken2, Rem2),
    append(Taken1, Taken2, Pile0),
    mix(Rem1, Rem2, Pile1),
    append(Pile0, Pile1, Pile).
```

It seems you need to accumulate the 'shirts' (as list atoms). Here, we are recursively appending them onto the third argument of `mix/3` (`Pile`), until the base case (the first clause) is hit when both input lists are empty lists (note that the cut `!` is necessary here as the binding pattern for the second clause matches the first, so we want to exclude it). The behaviour of the second clause, which takes a shirt from each input list for every step, requires that they must have been of equal length to start with.

To test this, I used the following definition of `takeshirt/4`:

```
takeshirt(Ps, _, [P], Rem) :-
    select(P, Ps, Rem).
```

Note that the second argument here is unused, as `select/3` is being used to take a single element (a shirt) from the list, and return the remainder. The absence of a cut (`!`) after the `select` allows this predicate to backtrack in selecting all other elements (shirts) from the list. If we now execute your example query with this definition, we can get:

```
1 ?- mix([a,b],[c,d],NewPile).
NewPile = [a, c, b, d] ;
NewPile = [a, d, b, c] ;
NewPile = [b, c, a, d] ;
NewPile = [b, d, a, c] ;
false.
```

...we can see that `mix/3` enumerates all possible 'piles' on backtracking by taking a shirt from the first pile (first input list), then a shirt from the second pile (second input list), and so on, until both input lists are empty. If your definition of `takeshirt/4` doesn't leave choice-points, (is non-backtracking), then you could only get one solution, if any.

Comment: The cut is not necessary as `select` will fail on an empty list.

Comment: @larsmans: The cut may not be strictly necessary here if the implementation of `takeshirt/4` fails on an empty input list. In my example it might if `select/3` does, as you say, but that was just _my_ version for testing; I haven't assumed anything about the implementation of `takeshirt/4` that @shaungus has but hasn't revealed, except for the interface.

Comment: I'd assume a predicate that takes *n* things from a pile would fail if there aren't *n* things on the pile; that would be the Prolog way. But fair enough, +1 for showing the OP how to use `select`.

Comment: Thanks; and, agreed. If `takeshirt/4` fails on empty input lists as we would reasonably expect, the cut as the subgoal of the first clause of `mix/3` is not necessary, but if present, is otherwise known as a 'grue' cut (green or blue cut, as defined by O'Keefe) - one that simply serves to increase execution efficiency and doesn't have an effect on the logical semantics of the program. As a matter of course, I'd typically add grue cuts like this where they are obvious, but perhaps I've been programming PROLOG for too long... ;-)

Comment: I tried your version, it doesnt work if the piles are of different length, also it always produces the results in the same order for a set of piles. One way would be to accumulate all the NewPiles and then choose a random one of them...lets say I got 20 items in each pile, that´s quite many different list combinations :)

Comment: @shangus: If you want to cope with piles of different length, you'll need to modify the predicate - I based my answer on your initial formulation of the `mix/3` predicate behaviour, which requires input lists of equal length. I assume you have a different implementation of `takeshirt/4` which is random. To cope with piles of different length, you can (for example) change the base cases to: `mix([], R, R) :- !.` and `mix(R, [], R) :- !.`, which adds any remaining shirts to the pile, or `mix([], [_|_], []) :- !.` and `mix([_|_], [], []) :- !.`, which throws away any extra shirts left.